# Best way to check deleted item when doing data synchronization?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, database-design, synchronization

I have a system that periodically calls an API to fetch a list of attendees for an event, and store/synchronize the attendees in my local RDB.

Each record has a timestamp field which I can use to check **updated/new** records.

However I don't really have an elegant solution for checking **deleted** records. Is matching each record ID against my local DB the only viable way of finding which items are deleted?

Comment: How is a "deleted" item indicated by the API?  Does the API always return the entire list?

Comment: Provide a _short_ list of Local and API names and timestamps and explain what should happen with each.

Answer (score 0):

If the API returns the entire list, then start this way:

1. Put the list into another table, say, `List`.
2. See who is new via `FROM List LEFT JOIN Local USING(name) WHERE Local.name IS NULL`.  (It is unclear how the timestamp factors in.)
3. To see who is deleted, swap the table names.

Comment: Hi thanks for the idea, basically each user would have a status field indicating whether it is deleted. However, I don't think I can use join to check deletes since the table can have other users for other events.

Comment: `JOIN .. ON user_id` and `WHERE should-be-deleted`